# Cross platform file archiving

Tags: c++, cross-platform, zip, tar, compression

I need to archive several files into one file (like a tar file does) programmatically using C++ on both Linux and Windows. It doesn't necessarily need to be a tar file, any compressed/uncompressed file format that can be used on both OS' will do. Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) is a library for Linux and Windows. It can be statically linked against in Windows, and some Linux distros have the libarchive libraries already installed

Answer (score 3):

See [MiniZip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) library, a pure C++ cross platform Windows/linux.

Comment: I'm looking for documentation or an example for making an archive, but I'm finding nothing. Can anyone post a link?

Answer (score 2):

If the LGPL license is ok for you take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/ I do not think that the compression part of the program is very close tied up with windows. So just get the part you need from it, it supports a lot formats: 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP, WIM, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD, WIM, XAR, Z.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [zlib](http://zlib.net/). Look at the Related External Links section of that page for links to resources and dlls for compiling this on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP has built-in zip file handling

on *nix you can use `zip` and `unzip`